# Inserting XElement to surround another XElement with LinqToXml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Let´s say I have the following xml,

```
<Where><BeginsWith>...</BeginsWith></Where>
```

and now I want to "insert" an `<And>` clause that surrounds the BeginsWith clause so it looks like this afterward,

```
<Where><And><BeginsWith>...</BeginsWith></And></Where>
```

How do I accomplish that with LinqToXml?

The Add method where I essentially do 
**`where.Add(new XElement("And"))`** will only add the the "And" after BeginsWith, like this,

```
<Where><BeginsWith>...</BeginsWith><And /></Where>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Get the BeginsWith element
- Call [`XNode.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) on it to remove it from Where
- Add the And element
- Add BeginsWith to the And element (or create the And element using it as the content to start with)

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XElement where = XElement.Parse
            ("<Where><BeginsWith>...</BeginsWith></Where>");
        XElement beginsWith = where.Element("BeginsWith");
        beginsWith.Remove();
        where.Add(new XElement("And", beginsWith));
        Console.WriteLine(where);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is any atomic operation that will do this for you. You will likely have to add the "And" element, then move the BeginsWith element inside it.